# How to add a legend to raster's RGB plot?

Tags: r, plot, raster

I wanted to know how I can add a triangle legend to `raster`'s `plotRGB`, so that each angle corresponds to one of raster layers.

```
r <- raster(ncols=10, nrows=10)
r1 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r2 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
r3 <- setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))
s <- stack(r1,r2,r3)
plotRGB(s, 3, 2, 1, stretch='hist',interpolate=T)
```